# My rewritten url redirecting but to a website without css or any other rule being applied

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

This is my original url

```
http://havemybooks.com/blog_single?blog_no=39&blog=Ten%20quotes%20by%20national%20leader%20to%20make%20this%20independence%20day%20more%20speacial.
```

This is my rewritten url

```
http://havemybooks.com/blog_no/39/blog/Ten%20quotes%20by%20national%20leader%20to%20make%20this%20independence%20day%20more%20speacial.
```

Here is the code I'm using in .htaccess. I don't know a much about .htaccess so I'm using htaccess generator tool.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^blog_no/([^/]*)/blog/([^/]*)$ /blog_single?blog_no=$1&blog=$2 [L]
```

This is the error I get when I inspect elements of my website.

Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What is the problem with my code  ? Both results should have been same as I'm just rewritting the url.

Comment: Does the server have `mod-rewrite` enabled? What do you see when you visit the prettier URL?

Comment: If your CSS/other assets is not working, add `<base href="/">` to your `<head>`.

Comment: Yes I have mod rewrite enabled that's why the new link is working. @hjpotter92

Comment: @MikeRockett I didn't even notice that OP has put in the actual URLs here. :| I assumed that it must be `example.com` urls.

Comment: So how will they notice the difference between the sites if exact url is not there. @hjpotter92

Comment: I am getting this error when I try to inspect elements of the rewritten url   Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html. @MikeRockett

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Mike commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39053147/my-rewritten-url-redirecting-but-to-a-website-without-css-or-any-other-rule-bein?noredirect=1#comment65455744_39053147) above, you just need to load the static content from site root. Current, all your URLs are being rendered relative to the page you are visiting.

Add a [`base` tag](https://devdocs.io/html/element/base) in the `<head>` of you pages, and the content will load as required.

```
<base href="www.example.com/">
```